# Angular - The requested URL /home was not found on this server

Tags: angular, url, http-status-code-404

I am gonna be very brief.

I have an Angular project with simple navigation menu (routerLinks). 
Everything work as it is supposed to if it is on localhost, powered by angular cli.

But when I deploy it on a real server (i don't have any VPS or any other server, just folder where I can put my files) weird thing starts happening.

The app is functional, navigation is functional, routeLinks routing, but when I refresh a browser or try to write something manually into URL line, every time I get 404 Not found. (so i am in [domain]/home - everything is ok, but when i refresh browser, i got 404 /home not found.

Maybe I am looking for a problem in a bad place and it is not a problem of angular but about HTTP requests (i don't know much about it).

Do you have any idea where I should start?

Thank you, Pavel F.

the project what i am talk about: http://www.pavel-challenge.cz (no, this is not ad :D )

> app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { PassionsComponent } from './passions/passions.component';
import { QuestionComponent } from './question/question.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './about/about.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { KnowledgeComponent } from './knowledge/knowledge.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'knowledge', component: KnowledgeComponent },
  { path: 'questions', component: QuestionComponent },
  { path: 'passions', component: PassionsComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

> navbar.component.html

```
  <ul>
    <li><a routerLink="/about">About</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/knowledge">Knowledge</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/questions">Questions</a></li>
    <li><a routerLink="/passions">Passions</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: where are codes?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly I should to show. Everything is working, except the problem what I have described. So maybe the problem is in ignoring something rather than in bad coding.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

FIXED: (for Apache HTTP server)

i created .htaccess file and put it into root folder on a provider side.

> .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I have uploaded my angular app (prod) to a unix server which runs apache. I have inside /htdocs/testApps/myAngularApp. I tried including that file in my root directory /htdocs/testApps/.htaccess and edited the rewriteRule to `RewriteRule . /myAngularApp/index.html [L]`. But still I can't reload my page. What's wrong with what I'm doing?

Comment: It helped, thank you! I have added the `.htaccess` file into _my project_ root folder. For Angular it is the subfolder of the `dist` folder.

Comment: I add '.htaccess' in /var/www/html/dist and in /var/www/html and I restart apache2. I have always the same error 404 not found.

Answer (score 7):

In case you are deploying on Apache , you should enable the mod_rewrite module :

**sudo a2enmod rewrite**

Then Restart Apache , **sudo systemctl restart apache2**

After that do the suggested changes in the .htaccess as per the previous answer

Answer (score 4):

The matter is in your HTTP server configuration.

you have to make all the URL after your hostname pointing to the HTML resource embedding your angular application.

like in NGINX :

```
 location / {
       root <path to index.html>;
       try_files $uri  /index.html =404;
( if ressource exist serves it, likes images, else load index.html to load angular app )
    }
```

[here is the official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration)

while navigating after initial load, the angular router take the lead, and display data after location change dynamically without http request.

But if you load directly to <...>/home the http server certainly try to load a file home.html, and then send a 404.

Comment: Oh... It seems logical, i have seen it before i have ask here. The question now is: "how can i configure server if i dont have any/or at least i dont know about any. Can i configure it on my app side ?

Comment: Unfortunatly no you cant. The matter here is http relevant. Way before angular kicks in. Unless you create symlink to index.html for every route of your app like home -> index.html in your app directory.

Comment: Ok, now I know my provider using Apache servers. Do you think I can figure out my problem with creating a .htaccess file with appropriate settings?

Comment: yes i think so, you can use the .htaccess in example at https://angular.io/guide/deployment#development-servers

Comment: Thank you, Pierre. We got it :)

Answer (score 2):

You must use hashLocationStrategy to maintain route states in your app when refreshing the page or typing url manually

In your app.module.ts:-

```
...
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';

...
providers: [... , {provide:LocationStrategy, useClass:HashLocationStrategy}],
```

The reason the URL was not found is that the URL handling and routing are done by the angular app itself instead of the server as done traditionally. So if the url typed requests for home or about section of the website, it sends those request to server which can't be found on the server since the page is loaded within the app itself beforehand. That's why the server doesn't returns anything even in case of refresh if you care in a specific page instead of root /.

Answer (score 1):

The same problem occurred to me, but the error persisted after editing the **.htaccess file** and enabling the **mod_rewrite** module.

What I needed to do additionally was to add the snippet below inside of my apache site config.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/back-office>
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

- Make sure that you've completed the previous two steps (**mod_rewrite** and **.htaccess**) in previous answers.
- Make sure that the **path** specified in the **directory tag** points to your **angular dist folder**.

Additional [info](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride).